# Ao fechar modal retornar ao formulário de origem passando parâmetros

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, modal

Estou efetuando uma consulta em meu BD em uma `janela modal`, agora depois da consulta feita, preciso ao clicar em um botão enviar os parâmetros selecionados para a página chamadora e jogar esses parâmetros em alguns `inputs`, anteriormente tinha feito isso usando uma `url` devolvendo os valores desejados fechando a `modal`, mas tinha um problema, isso causava um novo carregamento da página fazendo com que os dados anteriormente preenchidos de outros campos se perdessem.

Fiz isso ao clicar no botão enviar:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" data-toggle="modal" onclick="EnviaDados()"> enviar </button>
<input id="NomeCooperante" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Retorno->NomeCooperante; ?>" />
```

E na página de retorno assim:

```
function EnviaDados() {
    $('#ModalCooperante').modal('hide'); 

    // var valor = $('input[type="text"][name="NomeCooperante"]').val();    
    var NomeCoop = $(this).attr("NomeCooperante");
    alert("COOPERANTE: " + NomeCoop);

}
```

Fiz alguns testes, o resultado do alert está sendo:

```
COOPERANTE: [Object HTMCollection]
```

O que tenho é isso, a busca:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E os campos que preciso preencher no retorno.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você consegue incluir um **[exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para o meu problema, foi essa:

Passei os parâmetros obtidos na busca para a chamada de uma função, ficou assim:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="mostraDados('<?php echo $Retorno->IdCooperante; ?>','<?php echo $Retorno->NomeCooperante; ?>','<?php echo $Retorno->IdPropriedade; ?>','<?php echo $Retorno->LocalVistoria; ?>','<?php echo $Retorno->IdMunicipio; ?>','<?php echo $Retorno->IdUF; ?>')"> enviar </button>
```

Na página chamadora, recuperei os parâmetros e atribui aos campos, como segue:

```
function mostraDados(pIdCooperante,pNome,pIdPropriedade,pVistoria,pUF,pIdMunicipio) {   

    // ATRIBUINDO VALORES RETORANDOS AOS CAMPOS
    $("#ID").val(pIdCooperante); 
    $("#Cooperante").val(pNome); 
    $("#Propriedade").val(pIdPropriedade);
    $("#Vistoria").val(pVistoria);
    $("#UF").val(pUF);
    $("#Municipio").val(pIdMunicipio);  

    $("#ModalCooperante").closemodal(); 

}
```